Why do most philosophers believe in contingent things?
Something being contingent implies that it could have been otherwise. But we’ve only ever observed one sequence of events in the universe. As such, alternative sequences of events have only been imagined, never actually seen.
Why does imagining something, even if it’s imagined according to some laws, imply that things could have occurred otherwise? Why do most philosophers believe in contingent things?

There is only one past timeline but we see many in the future. In other words,  most people think the future is fundamentally different from the past.  Until the future has become the past.

Relevant: https://www.reddit.com/r/askphilosophy/comments/vr4zep/what_is_the_knockdown_argument_against/

You can imagine multiple pasts and multiple futures. But we only ever see one future occurring. @Philomath

Everyday experiences simply justify contingency, even insurance claims are contingent upon certain things in the future without a necessary payout, yet the learned Helmholtz once hinted the vast subconscious or unconscious intentional nature of the mind which implies the contingent nature of things to come to be perceived indirectly...

@KristianBerry Why believe in contingent events?

@Syed Ah, yes, I was affirming your point of view. I just thought that the idea of a timeline might be helpful to show that the present only looks special but if we look from the outside, or to history it's easy to see that past and future are not fundamentally different..So, for the record: I agree with you on this point.

The difference is this.
Suppose I roll a dice and it shows a six. 1) Perhaps there was no way in which it could have been a five instead, because a six was predetermined in a way that every other option was ruled out. Now compare that to the question of whether I could have rolled a seven. 2) I know that I could not, because the dice doesn't have a face showing seven spots.
In the case 2), we have an option that is definitely ruled out by the characteristics of the dice. In the case 1) we have an option that is not ruled out by the characteristics of the dice- sure, it would be ruled out if everything was predetermined, but we don't know for sure that everything is predetermined, so it's a possibility.
If you can appreciate the differences between cases 1) and 2) then you should be able to answer your own question. If you can't see the difference, you will never be able to see the answer to the question.
